# Nodejs, Express, Javascript Stack using Mocha and Chai Dependancies for TDD Testing

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, mocha.js, chai

Using a nodejs, javascript and express stack I am testing out examples from the book "Web Development with Node and Express: Leveraging the Javascript Stack". I am currently running an example to preform Page Testing using mocha and chai. [github link](https://github.com/EthanRBrown/web-development-with-node-and-express)

Can someone explain where I will see the result of a test passing or failing? It could be possible the env is not set to development, and that could be anther reason for me not seeing changes during the test. I am not certain what I should be observing. For example, should there be output in the browser or the console? Below is the partial code I am implementing:

meadowlark.js

```
app.use( function( req, res, next){ 
     res.locals.showTests = app.get(' env') !== 'production' &&     
     req.query.test = = = '1'; next(); }); 

app.get('/ about', function( req, res) { 
       res.render(' about', { 
          fortune: fortune.getFortune(),
          pageTestScript: '/qa/tests-about.js' } ); });

// routes go here....
```

In the head:

```
<head> 
<title> Meadowlark Travel </ title > 
{{# if showTests}} 
     <link rel ="stylesheet" href ="/vendor/ mocha.css"> 
{{/ if}} 
<script src ="// code.jquery.com/ jquery-2.0.2. min.js" > </ script > 
</head >
```

In the body

......

```
{{# if showTests}} 
      < div id =" mocha" > </ div > 
      < script src ="/ vendor/ mocha.js" > </ script >
      < script src ="/ vendor/ chai.js" > </ script > 
      < script > 
           mocha.ui(' tdd'); 
           var assert = chai.assert; 
      </ script > 
      < script src ="/ qa/ tests-global.js" > </ script > 
      {{# if pageTestScript}} 
            < script src ="{{ pageTestScript}}" > </ script > 
      {{/ if}} 
      < script > mocha.run(); </ script > 
      {{/ if}} 
</ body >
```

qa/tests-global.js

```
suite(' Global Tests', function(){ 
    test(' page has a valid title', function(){ 
    assert(document.title && document.title.match(/\ S/) && 
           document.title.toUpperCase() != = 'TODO'); }); });
```

qa/tests-about.js

```
suite('" About" Page Tests', function(){ 
       test(' page should contain link to contact page', function(){ 
              assert( $(' a[ href ="/ contact"]'). length); }); });
```

To test this the instruction tell me the following: "Now, add test = 1 to the querystring (http:// localhost: 3000/? test = 1), and you’ll see the tests run on the page." I don't see any difference with ?test=1 added to the query string. Any help would be appreciated.

Update:
Following the same app.use order as the author did within the meadowlark.js server I was able to successfully get the test displayed in the browser.

Comment: It looks like `res.locals.showTests` isn't getting set properly in the `app.use()` block.  You could try doing a `res.locals.showTests = true` to see if you then see the test results and then debug from there.  They will appear on the web page in your browser.

Comment: Setting it to true did not work. When I use ?test=1 in the query string, I looked at the output form each argument. It appears the req.query.test is returning {} and the app.get('env') == development. I also inspected the browser and can see the Query String Parameters is setting test: 1. As a second step I ran ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha web.js and found as response of --> 0 passing (1ms). So far I have nothing passing or failing. It would be great to know how to make it pass or fail.